# Issue After Dnn Upgrade rollback

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

Recently I upgraded from Dnn 9.1.1 to Dnn 9.3.0 . Due to some error I had to rollback to backup taken of website and database earlier. Everything seemed fine except the message "Could not find stored procedure Personabar_Getusers" showing on clicking Users in persona bar.[image: Error Image]

Comment: This does not seem possible.  Try the rollback again, making sure to restore the old database, and clear out the website directory before restoring files.

9.1.1 doesn't use the Personabar_Getusers stored procedure.  Presumably there is a call to that from some code, indicating that you have 9.3.0 code in your directory..

Are you sure that is the stored procedure reported, not a GetUserBy<something else>

Comment: One possible note to this situation is that you are using a version of EVOQ - you should NOT follow the standard upgrade process for Evoq without consulting the mapping of Evoq versions to that of DNN Platform as it can cause all kinds of crazy results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this usually means that the upgrade steps had a mistake or something missing.  You're best off trying again after restoring to the original step.

Also, this is technically not DNN.  It's Evoq.  If this continues to occur, you should contact DNN Corp Support, as they have forked DNN for a long time, and they will need to support that.